# Android Update Entry

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I'm able to insert and retrieve the data into my database, however, I cannot update the records. it says no such column : userid1

```
public boolean updateEntry1(String user, String custName, String gender, String birthDate, String address)
{

   //create new record
    ContentValues updateEntryValues = new ContentValues();

   //Assign values for each row
    updateEntryValues.put(CUST_NAME,custName);
    updateEntryValues.put(CUST_GENDER,gender);
    updateEntryValues.put(CUST_DOB,birthDate);
    updateEntryValues.put(CUST_ADDRESS,address);


   //Insert the row
    Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT,"Inserted custName = " + custName + "gender =" + gender + "birthDate =" + birthDate + "address =" + address + " into table " + DATABASE_TABLE);

    if( _db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,updateEntryValues, USER_ID1 + " = " + user, null)<=0)
    {
        Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT,"Update entry where id = " + user + "Failed");
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT,"Removing entry where id = " + user + "Success");
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: The reason for that error message is that the tabe does not have a `userid1` column. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check that column is having or not in your table, if it exist then check condition with:

```
_db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,updateEntryValues, USER_ID1 + " = '" + user+"'", null)<=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error you describe, it seems like the table you are working with does not have a field named 'userid1'. Please post your onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method.

So, solution: Make sure that 'userid1' field actually exists.